# Numbers are being concatenated instead of being summed

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I am trying to add the value of cell `J3` to `M3` in worksheet "tableau" and put the sum in cell `H4` in worksheet "Company". However, when I write this code it returns the concatenated value something like 1500.60700.20

What could be the issue? I am new to Vba excel so please bear that in mind.

```
worksheet("tableau").Range("h4").Value = worksheet("Company").Range("J3").Value + worksheet("Company").Range("M3").Value
```

Comment: What are your input values in J3 and M3?

Comment: J3 holds the value 1500.60 and M3 holds the value 700.20

Comment: How are H4, J3 and M3 formatted? Are these numbers or strings?

Comment: they were formatted as strings i converted them to numbers (manually) and run the code and it worked like a charm thanks :) . how can avoid this type of problems directly in vba for example can i  i convert the cell value to numbers then use the range("j3").value+range("m3") diretly while coding ?

Comment: Use @braX answer below. The `val`-function converts strings to numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Val` function to convert them to numbers if they are formatted as strings:

```
worksheet("tableau").Range("h4").Value = Val(worksheet("Company").Range("J3").Value) + Val(worksheet("Company").Range("M3").Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could specify these values as numbers:

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long
i = worksheet("Company").Range("J3").Value
j = worksheet("Company").Range("M3").Value
worksheet("tableau").Range("h4").Value = i + j
```

---

Edit: This is similar to @braX comment, just another way of doing the work.

Comment: Your code is more cleaner and easier to understand for a beginner like me i ll use this version thanks.